# If derived class contains only base class element ,then downcast is possible using dynamic_cast in c++

Tags: c++

```
class Base { virtual void dummy() {} };
class Derived: public Base { // no new elements added }
```

I like to know that

```
base *bptr;
derived *dptr;
bptr=new base;
dptr=dynamic_cast<derived*>(bptr); // this is not working ,dptr is NULL
```

dynamic_cast can also downcast (convert from pointer-to-base to pointer-to-derived) polymorphic classes (those with virtual members) if -and only if- the pointed object is a valid complete object of the target type"

here the pointed object is base object and is same as target object.

so here "complete" means some other meaning

thanks

Comment: dynamic_cast<> cannot manufacture anything by itself. You, already, should be in possession of the memory containing the full object. It can "present" you an object of the requested (sub)type. Otherwise, it simply returns NULL.

Answer (score 0):

`dynamic_cast` will only succeed if the dynamic type of the object matches the type you're casting to. Here

```
bptr=new base;
```

points to a `base`, not a `derived`, so `dynamic_cast<derived*>` will fail; there is no `derived` object it could point to. `derived` is a different type to `base`, even if it doesn't declare any members beyond those in the base class.

Try

```
bptr=new derived;
```

and the cast should succeed.